# why can't i fake Thread.Sleep using VS fake framework

Tags: shim

I am having trouble finding faked Thread.Sleep in mscorlib.fakes library.
I am following direction at http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2012/04/27/using-shims-in-visual-studio-11-to-test-untestable-code/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.100).aspx shows Thread.Sleep is in mscorlib so I added its fake but System.Threading.Fakes namespace doesn't contain ShimThread nor StubThread.
Thread is a sealed class but VS fake framework should be able to fake static method in sealed class.

Comment: Are you trying to fake the Thread class or the Thread.Sleep method?  Why would you want to?

Comment: in my test i check if Thread.Sleep is being called when it shouldn't be. I am planning to add Assert.Fail() inside fake Thread.Sleep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the Shim framework cannot fake all .Net BCL classes in mscrolib and System, see: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549176.aspx#bkmk_limitations).

Unfortunately I couldn't find a list of types that aren't  supported. But it seems, primarily types that are not pure CLR classes or need OS functionality (Thread, FileSystemWatcher, ...) are not supported at this time.

Answer (score 8):

This is [very much possible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708916.aspx). By default Fakes framework doesn't generate shims for most types (including types in System.Threading namespace) of mscorlib because Fakes framework  itself makes use of mscorlib. So only a few of the types are shimmed,
However, you can configure this behavior by changing the mscorlib.fakes file added in your project.

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/">
    <Assembly Name="mscorlib" Version="4.0.0.0"/>
    <ShimGeneration>
        <Add Namespace="System.Threading!"/>
    </ShimGeneration>
</Fakes>
```

Now build the test project and you can see shims for types in the `System.Threading` namespace, including `ShimThread.SleepInt32`.

Read more about the .fakes xml file [on this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708916.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, this only got me halfway there. I did this, and it generated Stubs but not Shims.  Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: @Dustin Are you sure you used     <ShimGeneration> in the .fakes file? Because that should only generate shims and not stubs. I verify that it has worked for me and I have actually recently used it to intercept Thread.Sleep in multiple test cases.

Comment: To be more specific, I was attempting to shim System.ServiceModel.Channels. I definitely had <ShimGeneration> in the config file. I also tried <StubGeneration>. I ended up working around the issue though, so this problem is still unresolved.

Comment: this works, but do remember to rebuild your project after adding the code in order for the shim to show up in intellisense

Comment: It didn't work for me.When I build project compiler complains about AsyncLocal<> doesn't exist in the namespace 'System.Threading'